# Get Statement from JDBCTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have this code,

```
SimpleJdbcCall sql = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName(procName);
sql.execute(parameters);
```

And I believe that under the hood this uses a JDBC Statement. How can I get to that object from here? (I need to call the .getWarnings() method on the statement).

In other words how can I get SQLWarnings *AND* named parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a lot of digging, but here is how you can get SQLWarnings (or Print statements) *AND* named parameters. I extended JdbcTemplate and overrode the handleWarnings() method, and then passed that into my SimpleJdbcCall.

```
  public class JdbcTemplateLoggable extends JdbcTemplate{


    List<String> warnings;

    public JdbcTemplateLoggable(DataSource dataSource){
        super(dataSource);
        warnings = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    protected void handleWarnings(Statement stmt){
        try {
            SQLWarning warning = stmt.getWarnings();
            while(warning != null){
                warnings.add(warning.getMessage());
                warning = warning.getNextWarning();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<String> getWarnings(){
        return warnings;
    }
}
```

Then in my main program

```
JdbcTemplateLoggable template = new JdbcTemplateLoggable(dataSource);
        SimpleJdbcCall sql = new SimpleJdbcCall(template).withProcedureName(procName);
        sql.execute(parameters);
        for(String s : template.getWarnings()){
            log.info(s);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should perhaps use `JdbcTemplate` directly, or subclass it for usage with your `SimpleJdbcCall` (instead of a `DataSource`). `JdbcTemplate` has a method `execute(CallableStatementCreator, CallableStatementCallback)`, where a callback can be passed which gets the used Statement object.

You could override that method and wrap the passed callback with an own which stores the statement for later use.

```
public class CustomJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {

    private CallableStatement lastStatement;

    public CustomJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    public CallableStatement getLastStatement() {
        return lastStatement;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T execute(CallableStatementCreator csc, CallableStatementCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException {
        StoringCallableStatementCallback<T> callback = new StoringCallableStatementCallback<T>(action); 
        try {
            return super.execute(csc, callback);
        }
        finally {
            this.lastStatement = callback.statement;
        }
    }

    private static class StoringCallableStatementCallback<T> implements CallableStatementCallback<T> {

        private CallableStatementCallback<T> delegate;

        private CallableStatement statement;

        private StoringCallableStatementCallback(CallableStatementCallback<T> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        @Override
        public T doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            this.statement = cs;
            return delegate.doInCallableStatement(cs);
        }

    }

}
```

Note that the statement will most probably be closed when you retrieve it later, so `getWarnings()` may cause errors, depending on used JDBC driver. So maybe you should store the warnings instead of the statement itself.

Comment: Hey thanks for this solution. I'm a little new to Callbacks, so my question is, how will I actually call this in my program? (And does this change if I use a NamedJDBCTemplate?) namedCustomJdbcTemplate.execute(sql, params, <....>)

Comment: Upvoted for effort (and maybe it works too), but I figured out another solution which I'll post momentarily

Comment: @Steve your solution is **much** better.

Comment: Thanks @Florian, working through your code is what put the idea in my head.